# Math operator with indices and limits

Tags: math-operators

I have several `\bigoplus` operators, indexed by i from 1 to d, using `\bigoplus_i`

Now, I want to use these operations on terms indexed by j from 1 to d.  My first attempt to write this was
`\mathop{\bigoplus_i}_{j=1}^d`
which puts all subscripts and superscripts to the right.

I want the 'i' to be a subscript down and to the right, but I want 'j=1' to appear beneath the operator and 'd' to appear above.  I've tried a few different ideas (using '\displaystyle') without getting what I wanted.

Finally, `\mathop{\bigoplus{}_i}_{j=1}^d` worked; but I'm not sure the spacing is ideal.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would try with `sideset` from the `amsmath` package:

```
\begin{equation}
  \sideset{}{_i}\bigoplus_{j=1}^{d}
\end{equation}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you! 'sideset' seems to be exactly what I needed.  It puts the subscript at just the right level for the 'bigoplus'.

Answer (score 6):

try this one:

```
\[ \bigoplus\limits_{j=1}^d{}_i \]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; that also works.  Comparing your solution with Yuppie's and mine, I think my solution and yours are equivalent, putting the subscript at the default subscript height.  Yuppie's solutions puts the subscript lower and closer to the 'bigoplus'.